# No infinite-dimensional $F$-space has a countable Hamel basis

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, baire-category

> If $X$ is an infinite-dimensional topological vector space which is the union of countably many finite-dimensional subspaces, prove that $X$ is of the first category in itself. Prove that therefore no infinitely-dimensional F-space has a countable Hamel basis

This is an exercise from Rudin book. But I can't construct a set of nowhere dense closed sets which have union equal $X$. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: The linear span of the first $n$ vectors is nowhere dense.

Comment: Does $F$-space mean a Fréchet space?

Comment: @tomasz: F-space is a complete metric space.

Comment: @leducquang: then what do you mean by infinite-dimensional?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the complete metric topological space.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $\{e_n :n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is countable basis of $F$ and let denote by $$F_n =\{\lambda_1 e_1 +\lambda_2 e_2 +...+\lambda_n e_n :\lambda_1 ,\lambda_2 ,...,\lambda_n \in\mathbb{R}\} .$$
Then $$F=\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} F_j .$$
Since $F_n$ are closed and $F$ is complete then by Baire theorem we have that $F\subset F_k $ for some $k\in\mathbb{N} .$

Comment: absolutely right. Thanks so much.

Comment: Which Baire theorem are you using ?@leducquang