# Hamel Bases: Cardinality?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, hamel-basis

Every vector space admits a Hamel basis by AC.
That is there are maximally linear independent sets.
But how to prove their cardinalities necessarily agree?

..I couldn't really find any reference.

Comment: The easy answer is: this is just like the finite dimensional case, only with transfinite recursion to construct the bijection between the two bases, rather than just an induction up to $n$ or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a finite Hamel base, the vector space is finite dimensional and we can assume to be known that any basis has the same number of elements. 
Suppose that $\mathcal B$ is an infinite Hamel basis for the $F$-vector space $V$. Here  $F$ is the field of the scalars and I assume in this answer that $F$ has the cardinality of $\mathbb R$. Any vector is a finite linear combination of element of $\mathcal B$ in a unique way. Note that this imply that $V$ has the cardinality of $F$, because there is an injection.
$$
V\to \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left(F\cup F^2\ldots\cup F^n\right)
$$
So, there are two possibilities: $\mathcal B$ is infinite but countable or $\mathcal B$ has the continuum cardinality of $F$. For the case of *topological VS* The first possibility is ruled out here; [No infinite-dimensional $F$-space has a countable Hamel basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599903/no-infinite-dimensional-f-space-has-a-countable-hamel-basis).

Comment: The result you cite is for *topological* vector spaces. The space of sequences of reals (or whatever field) with finite support is decidedly a space with a countable basis.

Comment: How do you construct your injection? I think you miss substantially lot of expressions..

Comment: Many thanks to Milo Brandt  for having highlighted my oversight! The remark is absolutely correct. I will have to re-edit or erase the "answer".

Comment: I posted some results along these lines in [this 23 July 2000 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/plaintext.jspa?messageID=252940) (see also my follow-up [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/plaintext.jspa?messageID=252942)), which you're welcome to make use of to rewrite your answer, if you wish.