# Hamel in Banach Space

Tags: functional-analysis

A Hamel basis is a subset B of a vector space V such that every element v ∈ V can uniquely be written as

${\displaystyle v=\sum _{b\in B}\alpha _{b}b}$
with $α_b ∈ F$, with the extra condition that the set

${\displaystyle \{b\in B\mid \alpha _{b}\neq 0\}}$
is finite.
This property makes the Hamel basis unwieldy for infinite-dimensional Banach spaces.

Is this sufficient for the question. Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599903/no-infinite-dimensional-f-space-has-a-countable-hamel-basis?rq=1

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3171921/is-there-a-notion-of-a-continuous-basis-of-a-banach-space?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Almost always, when using a Banach space, we are interested in the topological properties related to the norm.  A *Hamel basis* is not useful in such situations.

In Banach space, there is a more useful notion of a *Schauder basis*, where we
allow infinite linear combinations
$$
x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k x_k
$$
but we require of course convergence in the norm.